# How to check for a number in a textbox using javascript HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if the value input in a HTML textbox contains a number, this is what I'm using so far, but it's not working, can anyone help? The text box would be a mix of letters and numbers, but I want to check if there are any numbers at all.

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="HasNumber"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById("input").value >= '0' && value <= '9' {
HasNumber.innerText = "Has Numbers" ; }
else {
HasNumber.innerText = "No Numbers" ; }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If my answer is work for you Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if input contain number by using Regex like Below Example:

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="HasNumber"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    const inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;

    let matchPattern = inputVal.match(/\d+/g);

    if (matchPattern != null) {
      HasNumber.innerText = "Has Numbers" ; 
    } else {
      HasNumber.innerText = "No Numbers" ; 
    }
  }
</script>
```